# Where sieve file must be located if dovecot runs with virtual_mailbox_maps

Tags: postfix, dovecot, sieve

I have `postfix` + `dovecot` install that uses
`virtual_mailbox_maps`

I want to do sieve for specific users.
where I should put the sieve file, since there are no user directories?

In dovecot configuration I have this:

```
plugin {
    sieve_extensions                    = +editheader
    sieve_editheader_max_header_size    = 1k

    # Protected special headers
    sieve_editheader_forbid_add         = X-Verified
    sieve_editheader_forbid_delete      = X-Verified X-Seen

    sieve_redirect_envelope_from        = recipient

    sieve                               = /etc/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
}
```

However, i do not want to use `default.sieve`, I want additional sieve file for specific users.

Answer (score 0):

After checking several websites, I did change my configuration like this and it works OK.

Not sure if this is best way, but seems clear enought.

```
plugin {
    sieve_extensions                    = +editheader
    sieve_editheader_max_header_size    = 1k

    # Protected special headers
    sieve_editheader_forbid_add         = X-Verified
    sieve_editheader_forbid_delete      = X-Verified X-Seen

    sieve_redirect_envelope_from        = recipient

    sieve_before                        = /etc/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
    sieve                               = /etc/dovecot/sieve_users/%d.%n.sieve
}
```

I know the dot "." in the `%d.%n.sieve` may backfire (SQL injection - like), but those files are created by me, so is OK.

Comment: There is a dovecot attribute named "home" which you can use too.

Comment: yes, but when you use it with virtual_mailbox_maps, it become messy fast...

Comment: is there a specific reason for you to use postfix delivery agent instead of dovecot delivery agent? Most of people would recommend dovecot as delivery agent.

Comment: I use dovecot delivery agent. Why you think I use postfix one?